# Text Label from variable value

Tags: python, variables, kivy, textlabel

Good afternoon, I have a problem, I would like to know if someone can help me:
The aim is to project its value into the text of a label on the next screen.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os.path
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
# modolo data
from datetime import datetime
# tabela
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

from plyer import notification

from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


from __future__ import print_function
import os.path
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
# modolo data
from datetime import datetime
# tabela
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

from plyer import notification

from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


KV = """
WindowManager:
    ScreenLogin:
        id: ScreenLogin
    ScreenPaginaInicial:
    PaginaEntradas:
        id: data_scr
    PaginaTipoEntrada:
    ScreenInicioProducao:  
        id: ScreenInicioProducao
    PaginaMovInterna:     
    PaginaMovExterna:      
    PaginaEditarArtigoOriginalInterna:
        id: PaginaEditarArtigoOriginalInterna
    PaginaEditarArtigoBob1Interna:
    PaginaEditarArtigoBob2Interna:
    PaginaEditarArtigoBob3Interna:
    PaginaEditarArtigoOriginalExterna:
    PaginaEditarArtigoBob1Externa:
    PaginaEditarArtigoBob2Externa:
    PaginaEditarArtigoBob3Externa:
<ScreenLogin>:
    name: "ScreenLogin"
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Image:
            size_hint: 1, 1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .85}
            source: 'G:\O meu disco\Gestao_Stocks\logo.png'
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            spacing: 5
            size_hint: 0.8, .6
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .4}
            Label:
                text: "Utilizador"
                size_hint_x: .3
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'middle'
                color: 0,0,0,1
                allow_copy: True
            TextInput:
                id: utilizador
                multiline: False
                halign: 'center'
                focus: True   
            Label:
                text: "Password"
                size_hint_x: .3
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'middle'
                color: 0,0,0,1
            TextInput:
                id: password
                multiline: False
                password: True
                password_mask: '#'
                halign: 'center'

            Label:
            Button:
                size_hint: 1., 1.
                text: "Login"
                on_release:
                    app.login()
                    app.root.current = "ScreenPaginaInicial"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
            Button:
                text: 'Sair da Aplicação'
                on_press: app.stop()                      
<ScreenPaginaInicial>:
    name: "ScreenPaginaInicial"
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Image:
            size_hint: 1, 1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .75}
            source: 'G:\O meu disco\Gestao_Stocks\logo.png'

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            spacing: 5
            size_hint: .7, .37
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .3}
            Label:
            Button:
                size_hint: 1., 1.
                text: "Armazém"
                on_release: 
                    app.change_screen('PaginaEntradas')
                    app.add_datatable()
            Label:
                text: utilizador.text
                size_hint_x: .3
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'middle'
                color: 0,0,0,1
            Button:
                size_hint: 1., 1.
                text: "Inicio da Produção"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "ScreenInicioProducao"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
            Button:
                text: 'Sair da Aplicação'
                on_press: app.stop()
"""




class ScreenLogin(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenPaginaInicial(Screen):
    pass


class PaginaEntradas(Screen):
    pass


class PaginaTipoEntrada(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenInicioProducao(Screen):
    pass


class PaginaMovExterna(Screen):
    pass


class PaginaMovInterna(Screen):
    pass


class PaginaEditarArtigoOriginalInterna(Screen):

    pass


class PaginaEditarArtigoBob1Interna(Screen):

    pass


class PaginaEditarArtigoBob2Interna(Screen):
    pass


class PaginaEditarArtigoBob3Interna(Screen):
    pass


class PaginaEditarArtigoOriginalExterna(Screen):
    tipo_movimentacao = StringProperty()
    pass


class PaginaEditarArtigoBob1Externa(Screen):
    pass


class PaginaEditarArtigoBob2Externa(Screen):
    pass


class PaginaEditarArtigoBob3Externa(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class AppStocks(MDApp):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data_tables = None

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def add_datatable(self):
        SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

        def main():
            creds = None
            if os.path.exists('token.json'):
                creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
            # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
            if not creds or not creds.valid:
                if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                    creds.refresh(Request())
                else:
                    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                        'client_secret.json', SCOPES)
                    creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
                # Save the credentials for the next run
                with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
                    token.write(creds.to_json())
            service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
            # ler informação do sheets
            sheet = service.spreadsheets()
            global dados_tabela
            dados_tabela = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId='1TUGChfPE3A7QdGFonDlEUDrtQIC0m9z2XhR2NYxeQTQ',
                                              range='Folha1!A2:AC').execute()
            screenText = StringProperty(dados_tabela)
            dados_tabela1 = dados_tabela['values']
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            main()
        pass
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        self.data_tables = MDDataTable(
            use_pagination=True,
            check=True,
            size_hint=(1, 1),
            column_data=[
                ("[size=11]Bloco", dp(22)),
                ("[size=11]Estante", dp(15)),
                ("[size=11]Prateleira", dp(15)),
                ("[size=11]Descrição", dp(70)),
                ("[size=11]Quantidade de MP", dp(30)),
                ("[size=11]Bloco 1", dp(15)),
                ("[size=11]Estante 1", dp(15)),
                ("[size=11]Prateleira 1", dp(15)),
                ("[size=11]Produto Bobinado 1", dp(70)),
                ("[size=11]Qtd Produto Bobinado 1", dp(30)),
                ("[size=11]Bloco 2", dp(15)),
                ("[size=11]Estante 2", dp(15)),
                ("[size=11]Prateleira 2", dp(15)),
                ("[size=11]Produto Bobinado 2", dp(70)),
                ("[size=11]Qtd Produto Bobinado 2", dp(30)),
                ("[size=11]Bloco 3", dp(15)),
                ("[size=11]Estante 3", dp(15)),
                ("[size=11]Prateleira 3", dp(15)),
                ("[size=11]Produto Bobinado 3", dp(70)),
                ("[size=11]Qtd Produto Bobinado 3", dp(30)),
                ("[size=11]Tipo Doc", dp(30)),
                ("[size=11]Data Doc", dp(30)),
                ("[size=11]ID2", dp(30)),
                ("[size=11]Quantidade 2", dp(30)),
                ("[size=11]Anulado", dp(30)),
                ("[size=11]Imagem", dp(30)),
                ("[size=11]Unidade de Compra", dp(30)),
                ("[size=11]Preço/1", dp(30)),
                ("[size=11]__PowerAppsId__", dp(30)),
            ],
            row_data=dados_tabela["values"]
        )
        self.root.ids.data_scr.ids.data_layout.add_widget(self.data_tables)
        self.data_tables.bind(on_row_press=self.on_row_press)
        self.data_tables.bind(on_check_press=self.on_check_press)

    def on_row_press(self, instance_table, instance_row):
        '''Called when a table row is clicked.'''
        start_index, end_index = instance_row.table.recycle_data[instance_row.index]["range"]
        start_index = (start_index / 29) + 1
        start_index_l = int(start_index) + 1
        print("linha_selecionada")
        print(start_index_l)
        # print(instance_table, instance_row)
        global linha_selecionada
        linha_selecionada = start_index
        SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

        def main():
            creds = None
            if os.path.exists('token.json'):
                creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
            # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
            if not creds or not creds.valid:
                if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                    creds.refresh(Request())
                else:
                    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                        'client_secret.json', SCOPES)
                    creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
                # Save the credentials for the next run
                with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
                    token.write(creds.to_json())
            service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
            # ler informação do sheets
            sheet = service.spreadsheets()

            dados_linha_clicada = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId='1TUGChfPE3A7QdGFonDlEUDrtQIC0m9z2XhR2NYxeQTQ',
                                                     range='Folha1!A' + str(start_index_l) + ':AC' + str(
                                                         start_index_l)).execute()
            print('dados' + str(dados_linha_clicada))
            global dados_linha_clicada_valores
            dados_linha_clicada_valores = dados_linha_clicada['values']
            print("dados_linha_clicada")
            print(dados_linha_clicada_valores)

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            main()
        pass

    def on_check_press(self, instance_table, current_row):
        '''Called when the check box in the table row is checked.'''
        # print((instance_table, current_row))
        print("intervalo")
        print(current_row)

    def change_screen(self, screen: str):
        self.root.current = screen

    def login(self):
        global utilizador
        utilizador = self.root.get_screen('ScreenLogin').ids.utilizador.text
        print(utilizador)
        password = self.root.get_screen('ScreenLogin').ids.password.text
        # Implemesta regras para acesso. Exemplo:
        if utilizador == '1' and password == '1' \
                or utilizador == 'x' and password == 'y':
            # If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
            SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

            def main():
                creds = None
                if os.path.exists('token.json'):
                    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
                # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
                if not creds or not creds.valid:
                    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                        creds.refresh(Request())
                    else:
                        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                            'client_secret.json', SCOPES)
                        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
                    # Save the credentials for the next run
                    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
                        token.write(creds.to_json())
                service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
                # ler informação do sheets
                sheet = service.spreadsheets()
                dados_registo_logins = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId='1YSFtrQIS3XfZHA7g67PxNaWcfF5uN_8ivrZvbqeZ2uU',
                                                          range='Folha1!A:B').execute()
                dados_registo_logins_valores = dados_registo_logins['values']
                n_linhas_registo_logins = len(dados_registo_logins_valores)
                print("nlinhas")
                print(n_linhas_registo_logins)
                linha_adicionar_dados_registo_logins = str(n_linhas_registo_logins + 1)
                adicionar_registo_logins = [
                    [utilizador, password, str(datetime.now())],
                ]
                # Escrever informação no sheets
                sheet = service.spreadsheets()
                dados_adicionar_logins = sheet.values().update(
                    spreadsheetId='1YSFtrQIS3XfZHA7g67PxNaWcfF5uN_8ivrZvbqeZ2uU',
                    range='Folha1!A' + linha_adicionar_dados_registo_logins, valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED",
                    body={"values": adicionar_registo_logins}).execute()
                notification.notify(title='Login', message='Login efetuado com sucesso!')

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                main()
            pass
        else:
            # If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
            SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

            def main():
                creds = None
                if os.path.exists('token.json'):
                    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
                # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
                if not creds or not creds.valid:
                    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                        creds.refresh(Request())
                    else:
                        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                            'client_secret.json', SCOPES)
                        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
                    # Save the credentials for the next run
                    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
                        token.write(creds.to_json())
                service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
                # ler informação do sheets
                sheet = service.spreadsheets()
                dados_registo_logins_erro = sheet.values().get(
                    spreadsheetId='1YSFtrQIS3XfZHA7g67PxNaWcfF5uN_8ivrZvbqeZ2uU',
                    range='Folha1!A:B').execute()
                dados_registo_logins_erro_valores = dados_registo_logins_erro['values']
                n_linhas_registo_logins_erro = len(dados_registo_logins_erro_valores)
                linha_adicionar_dados_registo_logins_erro = str(n_linhas_registo_logins_erro + 1)
                adicionar_registo_logins_erro = [
                    ['ERRO!' + utilizador, 'ERRO!' + password, str(datetime.now())],
                ]
                # Escrever informação no sheets
                sheet = service.spreadsheets()
                dados_adicionar_registo_logins_erro = sheet.values().update(
                    spreadsheetId='1YSFtrQIS3XfZHA7g67PxNaWcfF5uN_8ivrZvbqeZ2uU',
                    range='Folha1!A' + linha_adicionar_dados_registo_logins_erro, valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED",
                    body={"values": adicionar_registo_logins_erro}).execute()
                notification.notify(title='Login', message='Erro!')

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                main()
            pass
```

I have here part of my code, hope it's enough.

In short, I want to use the "utilizador" variable value, and insert its text inside a lable, I tried:

```
Label:
      text: utilizador.text
```

I've been looking for a solution for a long time, I've read everything but I can't solve it. My difficulty is that I have several screens, inside one of them I define a variable.

Comment: Try using method [`get_screen`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager.get_screen).

Comment: It didn't work, can you provide me with a practical example, please.
I don't know if the problem will be the solution or it will be me :)

Comment: Try posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by removing other dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your posted code is not a minimal reproducible example, but here is an example of one way to do what you want:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class ScreenLogin(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenPaginaInicial(Screen):
    pass

kv = '''
WindowManager:
    ScreenLogin:
        id: ScreenLogin
    ScreenPaginaInicial:
        id: ScreenPaginaInicial
    
<ScreenLogin>:
    name: 'ScreenLogin'
    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: utilizador
            on_text: root.manager.ids.ScreenPaginaInicial.ids.lab.text=self.text  # update Label whenever text changes
        Button:
            text: 'other Screen'
            on_release: root.manager.current='ScreenPaginaInicial'
    
<ScreenPaginaInicial>:
    name: 'ScreenPaginaInicial'
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            id: lab
            text: 'Abba'
        Button:
            text: 'other Screen'
            on_release: root.manager.current='ScreenLogin'
'''


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

TestApp().run()
```

Comment: thank you so much for your support, hope I can help you back, much appreciated, great job, your input has already helped me solve a lot of problems.

Comment: I want to use the "dados_registo_logins_valores" variable value, and insert its text inside a lable, is possible?

Comment: my question is:

if I have a variable defined inside the class "TestApp(App):" like:


`  def mov_int_1(self):
        l=MDLabel(text=dados_registo_logins_valores,pos_hint={'center_x':0.1,'center_y':0.5}, text_color=(0.5,0,0.5,1), font_style='Caption')
        ScreenPaginaInicial.add_widget(l)`


In short, I want to access the text(screen 2) that was generated by a variable in the previous screen(screen 1). And display(screen 2).

I hope I managed to explain. Sorry for the technical terms

Comment: If you use a [StringProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.StringProperty), you can just set the Label `text` to that property in `kv`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I made a new post with my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74705591/text-label-from-variable