# Text label from variable

Tags: variables, text, kivy, label, screen

Good afternoon, I have a problem, I would like to know if someone can help me: The objective is to display the text of a variable("value_to_display_1"- This variable is defined on the "ScreenLogin"), inside "ScreenDisplayLabel" inside a label or something else:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from plyer import notification
KV = """
WindowManager:
    ScreenLogin:
        id: ScreenLogin
    ScreenDisplayLabel:
        id: ScreenDisplayLabel
<ScreenLogin>:
    name: "ScreenLogin"
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            spacing: 5
            size_hint: 0.8, .6
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .4}
            Label:
                text: "User"
                size_hint_x: .3
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'middle'
                color: 0,0,0,1
                allow_copy: True
            TextInput:
                id: user
                multiline: False
                halign: 'center'
                focus: True   

            Label:
                text: "Password"
                size_hint_x: .3
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'middle'
                color: 0,0,0,1
            TextInput:
                id: password
                multiline: False
                password: True
                password_mask: '#'
                halign: 'center'
            Button:
                size_hint: 1., 1.
                text: "Login"
                on_release:
                    app.login()
                    app.root.current = "ScreenDisplayLabel"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"                  
<ScreenDisplayLabel>:
    name: "ScreenDisplayLabel"
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

"""
class ScreenLogin(Screen):
    pass
class ScreenDisplayLabel(Screen):
    pass
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass
class Teste(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
    def login(self):
        global user
        user = self.root.get_screen('ScreenLogin').ids.user.text
        print(user)
        password = self.root.get_screen('ScreenLogin').ids.password.text
        # Implemesta regras para acesso. Exemplo:
        if user == '1' and password == '1' \
                or user == '2' and password == '2':
                value_to_display_1 = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
                notification.notify(title='Login', message='Succsess!')
    def Extract_Value_Login(self):
        value_to_display_2 = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'
Teste().run()
```

I can't even just display the text of "value_to_display_2"

I've tried several ways to solve my problem, I've looked for alternatives all over the internet, but I haven't found a solution.

Comment: Could you localize the problem and fit the code in 100 lines, then they will help you faster, appreciate the time of other programmers

Comment: Have a look at [mcve].

Comment: I've already made the changes, I hope that's enough.
Thanks for the time you give me

Comment: To display text in your `ScreenDisplayLabel` first you need to add a `Label` etc. Then you can pass the desired text in several ways.

Comment: It also seems to me that it should be simple. I think some technical knowledge is missing, if you can demonstrate it to me with a practical example, I'll be grateful. I keep trying but nothing is working. Thanks for your time.